# Why is Mann-Whitney U-Test over an ExpressionSet yielding different results than original paper

Tags: r, microarray

I am trying to replicate the results of [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/onc2014136) paper roughly guided by [this](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/workflows/vignettes/maEndToEnd/inst/doc/MA-Workflow.html#) pipeline.
Basically, we are trying to detect a differential expression between mesenchymal and epithelial cells under cisplatin treatment vs control.
However, I am facing a problem when trying to calculate the p-value for the Mann-Whitney U-test. This is the part of the paper I am referring to:

> Robust Multichip Average (RMA) normalization was performed at the
> transcript level on the results from the Affymetrix Human Gene ST1.0
> arrays using Affymetrix Power Tool 1.14.4.1 for all 46 sham- or
> cisplatin-treated ovarian cancer cell lines. The normalized data were
> subsequently standardized using ComBat71 to remove the batch effect.
> In this experiment, the cisplatin treatment assay was performed in
> triplicate on 20 cell lines, while single assays (without replicate)
> were performed on the remaining 26 cell lines. Taking advantage of the
> triplicate data, potentially fragile probes with strong variations (an
> s.d. of >0.2) within the triplicates were removed, decreasing the
> probe number from 33 297 to 21 329. To perform a fair comparison, the
> triplicate data were then log-averaged into one value so that one
> result for each cell line could be used in the following analyses. To
> detect differential responses to cisplatin between epithelial- and
> mesenchymal-like cell lines, the transcriptomic responses to cisplatin
> were computed by subtracting the gene expression value of control
> (cisplatin untreated) cells from that of cisplatin-treated cells.
> Mann–Whitney U-test (P<0.01 as a cut-off value) was subsequently used
> to detect the differential transcriptomic responses between the
> expression changes by cisplatin treatment in epithelial-like cell
> lines with those in mesenchymal-like cell lines (Supplementary Table
> 3).

My p-values for a given gene are astronomically different to that of the paper...
Here is my code:

expr_f is the expression values matrix from the Expression set (log-transformed).
SDRF_f is the pData from the same expression set.
I am feeding into the wilcox.test function a vector of expression from epithelial cells (epi_values) and mesencymal cells (mes_values) for the same probe (8143663).

```
 genelist=rownames(expr_f)
epi_samples = rownames(subset(SDRF_f, SDRF_f[,"Classification"]=="Epithelial-like"))
mes_samples = rownames(subset(SDRF_f, SDRF_f[,"Classification"]=="Mesenchymal-like"))

epi_values = expr_f["8143663", epi_samples]
mes_values = expr_f["8143663", mes_samples]


wilcox.test(mes_values, epi_values, exact=TRUE)
```

In the paper, their p-value for this probe is 0.000372259258165627 while mine is 0.8785. The difference makes no sense at all to me.
I don't know if I am not quite getting the concept of the u-test, if I am using the function wrong, or if it's something else. Any input is appreciated

Comment: Cross-posted on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/467695/

Comment: Wow that is some difference particularly for the Mann-Whitney. You are using Wilcox of course. Regardless there is one possibility which I will mention below if I get chance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to check your pipeline in this regard. I ran the analysis and replicated as closely as I could their M&M (I didn't filter the "fragile probes" since you anyway care only about a specific probe). In any case, I get something relatively close to their result (P=0.004059), which is still one order of magnitude off, but without more detailed M&M, this is probably as close as I can get to their analysis. Here's what I did (if you prefer to read the notebook html, that is [here](https://bschiffthaler.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Public/sebio_14571.html))

````
library(Biobase)
library(GEOquery)
library(sva) # ComBat
library(oligo)
library(googlesheets4)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

#' Get the GEO dataset mostly for the phenoData annotation
gset <- getGEO("GSE47856", GSEMatrix =TRUE, getGPL=FALSE)
adf <- Biobase::phenoData(gset[[1]])
sampleNames(adf)

#' Read RAW cel files from the GEO data supplementary rar archive
#' https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE47856&format=file
#' In my case extracted to ~/Downloads/cel
#' Ensure that we read them in the same order as the phenoData object
celfiles <- sapply(sampleNames(adf), function(f) {
  pat <- paste0(f, ".*.CEL.gz$")
  dir("~/Downloads/cel", pattern = pat, full.names = TRUE)
})
raw_data <- oligo::read.celfiles(celfiles,
                                 phenoData = adf, 
                                 experimentData = experimentData(gset[[1]]))

#' Get the raw expression and RMA on transcript clusters
rma_expr <- oligo::rma(raw_data, target = "core")
rma_expr_assay <- assayData(rma_expr)$exprs

#' Use ComBat for batch effect removal
batch_data <- phenoData(rma_expr)[["batch:ch1"]]
cb_expr <- sva::ComBat(rma_expr_assay, batch_data)

#' Get supplementary table 1 from the paper (which I copied on this Google Sheet)
supp_data <- read_sheet("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142__1O35zvlttejvz62XQX33uLRJhqIDvb604smVSRo")

#' Match the 'cell line' phenotype from the phenoData to the sample info of
#' the supplementary table and extract the cell classification. Also remove
#' all white space and convert everything to lower case for easier matching.
#' Some cell lines also have a/b attached, so I'm dropping that to match them
#' up. Mayb not be correct to do that here and treat all a/b the same (?)
cell_line <- str_replace(
  str_replace(
  str_remove(
    str_to_lower(adf[["cell line:ch1"]]),
    " +"),
  "^tay$", "taya"),
  "dov13[ab]", "dov13"
)

sample_info <- str_remove(str_to_lower(supp_data$Sample), " +")
classification <- supp_data$Classification[match(cell_line, sample_info)]

#' Get the treament from the phenoData object
treatment <- adf[["treatment:ch1"]]

#' We'll need the geometric mean later (R has no built-in)
gm_mean = function(x, na.rm=TRUE){
  exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm=na.rm) / length(x))
}

#' Set up a tibble (==data frame) with all that info for your probe
tibble(Expression = cb_expr["8143663", ], 
       Line = cell_line, 
       Treatment = treatment, 
       Classification = classification) %>%
  # Summarise replicated data with the geometric mean
  group_by(Line, Treatment, Classification) %>%
  summarise(Emean = gm_mean(Expression)) %>% 
  # Make sure data is in order
  arrange(Line, Treatment, Classification)%>%
  # Calculate the difference between the cell types
  group_by(Line, Classification) %>%
  summarise(EmeanDiff = diff(Emean)) -> xdata

#' Test the difference
xdata <- split(xdata$EmeanDiff, xdata$Classification)
wilcox.test(x = xdata$`Epithelial-like`, y = xdata$`Mesenchymal-like`,
            exact = TRUE)

#' Session info
sessionInfo()
```
````

Comment: Hi @CSP it is certainly an interesting discussion and some good R coding. Could you look through this very detailed reply and comment please?

Comment: You were right, I had a minor mistake in my pipeline! Thank you for this answer, very detailed and useful!

Comment: Great that it worked. If this is answered, please accept the answer

Comment: Agreed @CSP please accept the above answer

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation here is paired versus unpaired.

Mann-Whitney is normally associated with unpaired data, but the authors may have performed a paired test. You performed an unpaired test and thus there is a massive discrepancy in results. The authors should have stated the effect of pairing - it that is what they did - but they are under no strict obligations to do so. You however have performed a Wilcoxan rank sign test, albeit the results shouldn't be so different.

Comment: In R, a two-sample `wilcox.test` (i.e. providing both x and y) is the same as a Mann-Whitney U test. From the docs:
>Performs one- and two-sample Wilcoxon tests on vectors of data; the latter is also known as ‘Mann-Whitney’ test.

Comment: Also they cannot do a paired test, since they have uneven groups (Epithelial vs Mesenchymal)

Comment: Okay fair point @BastianSchiffthaler , I'm wrong. I was aware of the ability of Wilcox to approximate Mann-Whitney ... if the samples are naturally unpaired ... again simply I'm wrong. Mann-Whitney is naturally unpaired so I was never really sure. The only thing I'd point out is that generally any bug can result in p<<0.01 but when p>>0.1 it difficult for a bug to achieve this.

Comment: The samples are unpaired, it was a mistake in my prior pipeline, but thank you for you very useful input!